# Cannot import cv2 on PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, opencv

I am trying to import `cv2` module in PyCharm, but it shows error.
I tried in terminal as well

```
pip install opencv-python
pip3 install cv2
pip install opencv-python
pip3 install cv2
```

and whatnot.

Trying to install `opencv-python` from terminal shows this

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.4.1.15)
```

and trying to install `cv2` from terminal shows this

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cv2
```

However, trying to import `cv2` on Pycharm shows this :

Pycharm Error Image

[image]

Comment: pycharm want to install `opencv-python` like `pip install cv2`, but he need to install it like `pip install opencv-python`

Comment: You use a mix of pip-pip3 on anaconda python. Why not  something one? Why not `conda install cv2` ?

Comment: it shows PackagesNotFoundError @Ingaz

Comment: Have you tried instructions from https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv?

Comment: I propose that you forget about `pycharm` for some time and create working python environment. Do you really need anaconda from start?

Comment: In case you want `pycharm` - create new environment for your project in project settings.

Comment: No, I don't need anaconda from start. Thank you for your suggestions. @Ingaz

Comment: Good luck! Try `pipenv` (without conda)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, install the package named `opencv-python` via `pip install opencv-python` or use the GUI.

Second, just input `import cv2`; that is ok.

Answer (score 11):

Go to File->Settings->Project Interpreter and then add by '+' button 'opencv-python' module on this repository.

It downloaded without an error for my PyCharm and also downloaded the dependencies as well.

Comment: For those having similar issues as the OP and have already tried the `pip install opencv-python` without success, this may be your correct answer. Go to the Interpreter, press the "+" button, search for "opencv-python", click "Install Package." After that, `import cv2` should work

Answer (score 0):

While creating a new project in PyCharm, please select 'Base Interpreter' option from drop-down similar to the one shown in this link:
[Creating new Project stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXW1p.png)

Next, after successful creation of project and after downloading the opencv-python, it looks a shown in this link:
[Success message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKKvG.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tired several solutions from internet.No luck. But below approach worked fine with me.

In the pycharm interpreter settings, I installed pip & opencv-python.
This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, maybe you should after doing all the above, just continue your code and it will work. it did for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).